# How to calculate $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy\cos(xy)-\sin(xy)}{x^2}$?

Tags: limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> How to calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy\cos(xy)-\sin(xy)}{x^2}$?

I've been trying to calculate this limit and, hopefully, it will be $0$.
I've tried to separate it in a multiplication of a limited function and a function that its limit that goes to zero, so I can assume it all goes to zero.

If anyone can solve this for me or give me tips, I'd be thankful.

Comment: Have you tried using the Taylor expansion of the cos and the sine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're interested in the behavior of $\frac{xy\cos(xy)-\sin(xy)}{x^2}$ as $(x,y)$ gets closer and closer to $(0,0)$, so we can assume that $y\neq 0$. This allows us to write
\begin{align}
\frac{xy\cos(xy)-\sin(xy)}{x^2} &= \frac{xy\cos(xy)-\sin(xy)}{x^2y^2}\cdot y^2\\
&= \frac{xy\cos(xy)-\sin(xy)}{(xy)^2}\cdot y^2\\
\end{align}
Since $xy\to 0$ as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$, this suggests considering the behavior of
$$\frac{t\cos(t)-\sin(t)}{t^2}$$
as $t$ tends to $0$.

Notice that $t\cos(t)-\sin(t)$ and $t^2$ both approach $0$ as $t\to 0$. Since
\begin{align}\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(t\cos(t)-\sin(t)\right)}{\frac{d}{dt} t^2} &= \frac{\cos(t)-t\sin(t)-\cos(t)}{2t}\\
&= -\frac{\sin(t)}{2}\to 0\text{ as }t\to 0
\end{align}
it follows from L'Hôpital's rule that
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t\cos(t)-\sin(t)}{t^2}=0$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy\cos(xy)-\sin(xy)}{x^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy\cos(xy)-\sin(xy)}{(xy)^2}\cdot y^2=0\cdot 0=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor series for both functions.  Numerator $\approx xy(1-\frac{(xy)^2}{2})-xy+\frac{(xy)^3}{6}=-\frac{(xy)^3}{3}$
As a result fraction $\approx -\frac{xy^3}{3}\to 0$.